# usar o classList.add

Tags: javascript

Tenho duas condições em um código javascript puro; se a requisição enviada via restful foi recebida pelo serviço eu mostro na tela uma frase na cor verde, se não, outra frase na cor vermelha. Estou tentando usar o classList.add para isso, mas não estou obtendo resultados:

```
      let erro = "";
      erro = "Categoria já existente no sistema";
      document.querySelector(".categoria-aviso").innerHTML = erro;
      erro.classList.add('erro');
```

Desta forma ele não está exibindo o texto na cor vermelha. Agradeço a quem ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Acontece que você está tentando adicionar uma classe *css* em uma `string` ao invés de um elemento e por isso não está funcionando.

Você **deve** armazenar o `input` com `document.querySelector` em uma variável e depois modificar essa variável.

**Segue exemplo:**

```js
let erro = "";
erro = "Categoria já existente no sistema";
let span = document.querySelector(".categoria-aviso");
span.innerHTML = erro;
span.classList.add('erro');
```

```css
.erro {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="categoria-aviso"></span>
```